# Using a function conditionally with gulp-if

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to conditionally change the paths to JS files when in production. I'm using `gulp-inject-string` along with `gulp-if` to call a function that inserts my remote path + the parent folder name of a series of html files:

````
```
...(require a bunch of stuff here)...
var inject = require('gulp-inject-string');

function getFolders(dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir)
        .filter(function(file) {
            return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
        });
}

function injectAfterEach(src) {
    var folders = getFolders(config.root.dest);

    var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
        if (folder !== 'base') {
            var fullPath = path.join(config.remotePath, folder, '/');
            console.log('folder: ' + fullPath);
            return gulp.src(src)
                .pipe(inject.afterEach('<script src="', fullPath))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tasks.html.dest))
        }
    });
    return tasks;
}

gulp.task('html', function() {

    return gulp.src(config.tasks.html.src)
        .pipe(gulpif(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production', injectAfterEach(config.tasks.html.src) ))
        .pipe(gulpif(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production', removeCode({ production: true })))
        .pipe(gulpif(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production', htmlmin(config.tasks.html.htmlmin)))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tasks.html.dest))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```
````

I keep getting a "dest.on is not a function" error, which I guess is because my `injectAfterEach` isn't returning a stream.Transform object? Can someone clarify the best way to run that function conditionally? My gulp is a little shaky, but I tried to reference the [api docs](https://gulpjs.org/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder) for this particular use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like the following.  I have simplified a few things so I could test it.

First point: your `getFolders()` function can be easily replaced with the `glob.sync()` see call [glob options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#options).  Since you apparently want only the folders, your glob pattern for the glob call MUST end with a "`/`", i.e. a `path.sep`.

The key point here to return a stream is the use of [gulp-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-merge) which allows you to return a merged stream of each of the folders.map individual streams.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('gulp-merge');
const gulpif = require('gulp-if');
const glob = require("glob");
const inject = require('gulp-inject-string');


function injectAfterEach(src) {

  const folders = glob.sync(src);
  console.log(folders);

  return merge(folders.map(function (folder) {

    console.log("folder basename = " + path.basename(folder));

    if (path.basename(folder) !== 'base') {

      let fullPath = path.join("RemotePath", path.sep, path.basename(folder), path.sep);
      console.log('fullPath: ' + fullPath);

        return gulp.src(path.join(folder, '*.html') )
            .pipe(inject.afterEach('<script src="', fullPath))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
      }
  }));
}

gulp.task('default', function() {

  return gulp.src('./htmlFolder')

    .pipe(gulpif(true, injectAfterEach('./htmlFolders/**/')))

      // just commented out for testing
      // .pipe(gulpif(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production', removeCode({ production: true })))
      // .pipe(gulpif(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production', htmlmin(config.tasks.html.htmlmin)))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
      // .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that - that was really helpful. I ended up breaking this out into its own gulp task, and it did the trick. Specifically, glob.sync() and gulp-merge got me where I needed to be.